# Grails / Gorm : Difference between declaring object and describing relationship?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I'm having trouble understanding the difference between declaring a domain-object in another domain and specifying the relationship between the domains.

Sample code:

```
class User { 
Book book
}
```

versus

```
class User { 
static hasOne = Book
}

class Book {
String name
}
```

Comment: the book class remains the same in both cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [hasOne](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/hasOne.html) relationship will put the key on the child object, so in the db you'll find `book.user_id` with hasOne rather than `user.book_id` if you just declare `Book book` on User.  You'll see the difference in the DDL generated if you use `grails schema-export`.

Here's the DDL with hasOne in place:

```
create table book (id bigint generated by default as identity (start with 1), version bigint not null, user_id bigint not null, primary key (id), unique (user_id));
create table user (id bigint generated by default as identity (start with 1), version bigint not null, primary key (id));
alter table book add constraint FK2E3AE98896CD4A foreign key (user_id) references user;
```

Here's the DDL with just `Book book` on User:

```
create table book (id bigint generated by default as identity (start with 1), version bigint not null, primary key (id));
create table user (id bigint generated by default as identity (start with 1), version bigint not null, book_id bigint not null, primary key (id));
alter table user add constraint FK36EBCB952E108A foreign key (book_id) references book;
```

Notice that the book table has the reference in the first example and the user has it in the 2nd.

Long answer:  I strongly recommend watching [Burt Beckwith's presentation](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/GORM-Performance) on GORM/collections/mapping.  Lots of great info around GORM and the consequences of various advantages/problems with describing relationships with hasMany/belongsTo, etc.

Comment: Hi Ted, Thanks so much for sharing the knowledge and the video! While doing research before asking the question (i even went to 5th page google results on multiple queries.) I actually came upon this video but quickly dismissed it. After watching just the first 15 min I feel I have learned so much stuff that I needed to know that wasn't covered in the books I have. I'm clearly new to grails but have a decent background on relational databases, this is my first time not actually coding the sql, so I was feeling very uneasy about efficiency. Thanks again!

Comment: Nice one, thanks. Just an advice, keeping the order of examples in the answer (as asked in the question) would help the reading. :)

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that when using hasOne the foreign key reference is stored in the child table instead of the parent table, i.e. a user_id column would be stored in the book table instead of a book_id column being stored in the user table. If you didn't use hasOne, then a book_id column would be generated in the user table.

There is an explanation and example in the [Grails documentation for hasOne](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/hasOne.html).

Hope this helps.